# Postfix expression (type-name){initializer-list}

Tags: c, language-lawyer, compound-literals

The section `6.5.2.5/4` provides an explanation about the `postfix-expression` of the form `( type-name ) { initializer-list }`. Here it is:

> If the type name specifies an array of unknown size, the size is
>   determined by the initializer list as specified in 6.7.9, and the type
>   of the compound literal is that of the completed array type. Otherwise
>   (when the type name specifies an object type), the type of the
>   compound literal is that specified by the type name. In either case,
>   the result is an `lvalue`.

I don't understand the wording `the type of the compound literal`. How is it even possible for a literal to have a type? Does the type of the corresponding unnamed object is meant by `the type of the compound literal`?

For instance

```
long long *longs = (long long []) {1333, 3123, 3, 122};
```

The `initializer-list` here is used to initialize an unnamed object of type `long long [4]`.

Also it is not clear what is the purpose of `In either case, the result is an lvalue`. When using in an `assignment-expression` the `lvalue conversion` is performed on the right operand so it is no longer an lvalue.

Comment: Why do you think there is any problem with literals having types? All literals have types. `3` is an `int`. `8.9` is a `double`. `"abc"` is an array of four `char` (including a terminating null). `(int []) { 4, 5, 2 }` is an array of 3 `int`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Because `3.19` provides a definition for _value_ as _precise meaning of the contents of an object when interpreted as having a specific type_. This made me think that "a type" was something related to an object anyhow. Literals like `3` and `8.9` does not have to be represented by objects and are not `lvalue`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, a "compound literal" means the object/value that a use of the "compound literal" language construct designates. Values/objects have types in C.

The purpose of making compound literals lvalues is so that code like
`int *x = &(int){42}; *x = 43;` works. It makes compound literals behave kind of like anonymous variables. (Not completely, though. Unlike regular variables, compound literals can't have storage class specifiers, which I personally consider a language defect.)

Answer (score 2):

The main purpose of compound literal is to provide an anonymous object, so you can have a pointer to an real object without creating a variable first.

It's an lvalue, which means that one may obtain it address. But, it's not *modifiable lvalue* though, just like an ordinary array object:

```
int a[] = {0, 0};
a = {1, 2}; // error, a is not a modifiable lvalue
```

But of course, you can modify it by using subscript operator or indirect pointer access:

```
a[0] = 1; // fine
(long long []) {1333, 3123, 3, 122}[0] = 1; // fine as well
```

Comment: Non-`const` compound literals *are* modifiable. But you're not using any and your code doesn't work because arrays (whether declared in a compound literal or regularly, or whether const or non-const) aren't modifiable lvalues.

Comment: Yeah, sure. I've extended the answer to make it more clear.

Comment: The problem is that the *type* you're using cannot be a type of a modifiable lvalue. It has nothing to do with it being a compound literal.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I'm not sure if this makes any sense, but given `struct strct {int a; int b;};` the following works fine: `struct strct strct = {4, 5}; (struct strct){1, 2} = strct;` and is permitted by the Standard.

Comment: @St.Antario that's basically the corollary to what I said above.